# collidesWith method AndEngine not working

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am having lots of problems with the collidesWith() method on AndEngine. I can see that on the screen, the player and coin sprites I have created are obviously colliding, yet the code below is not executing.

```
scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            checkCollision();
            scoreText.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        }
    });
    return scene;
}


public void checkCollision() {   
    if(player1.collidesWith(coin)) {
        player1.setColor(Color.RED);
        coin.detachSelf();
        score+=200;
    }
}

public void loadSprites() {   //This loads the sprites
    coin = new Coin(210, 220, this.coinTR,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    player1 = new Player(INITX, INITY, this.player,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            // this.runRight();
            if (this.jump) {
                this.jump();
                this.checkPositionForJump();
            }
        }

    };

}

public void jump() {   //This jump method is part of the player class, it just follows a parabolic path to jump
    this.mX+=SPEED;
    this.mY = (float) (((this.mX - (this.startX + this.VERTX)) * (this.mX - (this.startX + this.VERTX)))
            / (this.STRETCH) + this.startY + this.VERTY);
}
```

As you can see it just follows a parabolic path from wherever it is currently positioned.

In the checkCollision() method, the if statement never evaluates to true. I have tried every single method I know and cannot get it to work properly. The only time it pseudo works is when I set the sprites to be in the exact same initial position, but other than that it never works. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code here looks fine. Can you paste some more of you code? Especially the code related to the `player1` and `coin` sprites, such as where you set the sprites positions, their initialization etc.

Comment: I've added the code creating the sprites, I'm not sure if the jump method is what is messing up the collidesWith method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying a `sprite`'s location by setting its' `mX` and/or `mY` members can lead to the problems you're experiencing. It's always a good idea to use the setters for this.

Change the `jump` method (and any other place) so it uses `setX` and `setY` methods instead of `mX` and `mY`, and it should solve your problem.